# Display http pre-flight errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, http

I would like to display error details on a page for errors that produce no `request.responseText` value. Is there some other location this information is stored?

Chrome network tab shows it as following and some other things:

```
(failed) net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: you only have the status code to work with

Comment: status code is 0 in this case. There is a description  in chrome tools, I wash I could access in in javascript...